# Sending a Java object from my Android phone to my Computer

Tags: android, wireless, lan

I was wondering what the simplest program for sending an object from my Android phone to my computer wirelessly (via LAN) would be. I have created Java RMI programs with a server and multiple clients, so I have a grasp of the concept. However with android I'm just not sure where to start.

What I am aiming to do is send some sort of information (could simply be text) to my computer and my computer will do an action. I have the GUI interface's and the actions to be carried out all worked out, just the sending of some sort of information is getting me.

Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's not much different from sending data between regular computers. Basically you have the same options. Unless you have some special requirements, the most straight forward solution would be to just set up a ordinary server / socket.

A tutorial on the basics (including example code): http://www.ryerson.ca/~dgrimsha/courses/cps841/serverSockets.html